# Is it possible to build an app on the lock screen level?

Tags: java, android

So the use case is, before user wants to unlock the phone, they have to answer a quiz or watch a small video on the lock screen level then only they can access the home screen

Example

[image]

Regards

Comment: Sure! At least, if you work for a major vendor and can update production rom images. Otherwise, it's probably a tad more difficult.

Comment: Yes..you can create an app which will start over lock screen..just you have to search the code to open your app on pressing lock key...or else other option is you have to create the launcher app...which will act like a launcher